# ajaxStart function called after returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code that submits an ajax call to recalculate shipping tax and the total on an order in our system.  While the ajax call is loading I put a loading spinner in the shipping tax and total boxes.  When the call returns it populates those three fields with the numbers for the respective values.  The only problem is that once the fade is done the spinner comes back in the input fields and just stays there.  How can I get it to go away once the values are returned?

```
$("#recalc_btn").click(function(){
  //Grab the order number and site ID from the URL
  var order_id = getQueryVariable("o");
  var site_id = getQueryVariable("s");

  $(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#total_shipping').css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
    $('#total_tax').css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
    $('#order_total').css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
  });
  //Make an AJAX call for the updated shipping
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 20000,
    //Pass the order ID and site ID through post
    data: {
      'action': 'recalculate_shipping',
      'order_id': order_id,
      'site_id': site_id
    },
    //When success is true change the values of shipping and total and make them green
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#total_shipping").effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000);
      $("#total_tax").effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000);
      $("#order_total").effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000);
      $("#total_shipping").val(msg.shipping);
      $("#total_tax").val(msg.tax);
      $("#order_total").val(msg.total);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Since this is in a click handler, why do you need ajaxStart?  Why not just toggle CSS classes on those elements? Set them on where you currently have the ajaxStart stuff, then toggle them off in your success handler.

Comment: What is purpose of including `$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function (){})` within `.click()` handler? Does this attach multiple handlers at each click at `#recalc_btn` element?

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding about how ajaxStart works.  I assumed it would stop applying the code once the ajax call was complete.  It appears that that is not correct.

Comment: You can substitute `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax()` for `.ajaxStart()`

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute using `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax()` for attaching a new handler to be called at each click at element; use complete callback of `.effect()`

```
var totalShipping = $('#total_shipping')
  , totalTax = $('#total_tax')
  , orderTotal = $('#order_total');

$("#recalc_btn").click(function(){
  //Grab the order number and site ID from the URL
  var order_id = getQueryVariable("o");
  var site_id = getQueryVariable("s");

  //Make an AJAX call for the updated shipping
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 20000,
    beforeStart: function() {
      totalShipping.css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
      totalTax.css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
      orderTotal.css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
    },
    //Pass the order ID and site ID through post
    data: {
      'action': 'recalculate_shipping',
      'order_id': order_id,
      'site_id': site_id
    },
    //When success is true change the values of shipping and total and make them green
    success: function(msg) {
      totalShipping.effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000, function() {
           $(this).val(msg.shipping)
      });
      totalTax.effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000, function() {
           $(this).val(msg.tax)
      });
      orderTotal.effect("highlight", {color: '#84e779'}, 3000, function() {
           $(this).val(msg.total)
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This still does not work.  It behaves in the same way.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `background` from the elements?

Comment: Yes I have tried applying .css("background", "transparent") to all the elements both within the success and after the ajax function call and neither of them work as intended.  Within the success block it fills up the input with the spinner and after the ajax call the spinner never shows up.

Comment: _"and after the ajax call the spinner never shows up."_ This is expected result, yes? That is, for the spinner to be removed at completion of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: Yes, but the spinner never comes. I want the spinner to be in the input field why the ajax call is processing and then disappear when the data is returned which is not the effect I am getting.

Comment: Perhaps the `$.ajax()` call completes before the image is loaded as `background` of elements?

Comment: I doubt that.  If you remove the `.css("background", "transparent")` the spinner shows up for quite a while.  The ajax call takes a noticeable amount of time to complete and populate the fields.

Comment: @shoes _"I doubt that."_ Have you checked `Timeline` of request for `.gif` at `Network` tab? Do the requests for images complete before ajax completes?

Comment: Yes. The ajax call takes roughly 7 seconds to complete and the image call takes 1 ms

Comment: Though the images are not displayed? Are the elements `css` set to `display:none`, or is `opacity` set to less than `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just reverse the process by setting to none?

```
$("#recalc_btn").on("click", function() {
  //Grab the order number and site ID from the URL
  var order_id = getQueryVariable("o");
  var site_id = getQueryVariable("s");
  var mythings = $('#total_shipping').add('#total_tax').add('#order_total');
  mythings.css("background", "url('http://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/pages/images/en/share/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat left center");
  //Make an AJAX call for the updated shipping
  var myajax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 20000,
    //Pass the order ID and site ID through post
    data: {
      'action': 'recalculate_shipping',
      'order_id': order_id,
      'site_id': site_id
    }
  });
  myajax.done(function(msg) {
    var mythings = $('#total_shipping').add('#total_tax').add('#order_total');
    mythings.effect("highlight", {
      color: '#84e779'
    }, 3000);
    $("#total_shipping").val(msg.shipping);
    $("#total_tax").val(msg.tax);
    $("#order_total").val(msg.total);
  });
  myajax.always(function(msg) {
    var mythings = $('#total_shipping').add('#total_tax').add('#order_total');
    mythings.css("background", "none");
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  This results in the input field being filled up with with the loading gif after the ajax is done.

Comment: Might have to use `mythings.css("background-image", "none");`

Comment: Changing that makes it go back to its original behavior where the wheel returns once the fade out of the highlight is done.

Comment: I put a simple test up here:  click one button to "circle" the other to clear and it does...https://jsfiddle.net/evq3jj80/